# Gson parse an Object from empty string

Tags: json, gson

When I use GSON deserialize a JSON String, it throws `JsonSyntaxException`. How can I deal with it?

```
{"QueueNum":1,"Result":"2","ResultMessage":"201","ReturnValue":"","TS":1448443938}
```

```
public class Response<T> {
    private int Result;
    private long TS;
    private float ResultMessage;
    private int QueueNum;
    private T ReturnValue;
}
```

Comment: which gson version are you using? It is working for me for v2.5.

Comment: Here is an example http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2015/11/serializing-and-deserializing-json-from.html

Comment: i got the same problem, and i think it's servers problem. so i ask it change to null.